# Toggle selectedRange attributes in UITextView

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, uifont

I have created a button that I want to check if text is selected then if so toggle bold and unbold over the selectedRange when tapped. At the moment my code will just change the selectedRange to bold and I can't undo it or check if there is a selection. How can I achieve this?

```
func bold() {
    if let textRange = selectedRange {
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)]
        noteContents.textStorage.addAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], range: textRange)
    }
```

Comment: simple `private var lastSelectedRange: NSRange?` and set it while bolding

Comment: Enumerate the attributedString for that selectedRange looking at the font attribute. Check if it's bold or not, reverse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
func toggleBold() {
    if let textRange = selectedRange {

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(attributedString: noteContents.attributedText)

        //Enumerate all the fonts in the selectedRange
        attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: textRange, options: []) { (font, range, pointee) in
            let newFont: UIFont
            if let font = font as? UIFont {
                if font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold) { //Was bold => Regular
                    newFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: font.pointSize, weight: .regular)
                } else { //Wasn't bold => Bold
                    newFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: font.pointSize, weight: .bold)
                }
            } else { //No font was found => Bold
                newFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold) //Default bold
            }
            noteContents.textStorage.addAttributes([.font : newFont], range: textRange)
        }
    }
}
```

We use `enumerateAttribute(_:in:options:using:)` to look for fonts (since bold/non-bold) is in that attribute.
We change it according to your needs (bold <=> unbold).

Comment: Thanks! Can I change this to allow that if there is no selected range that the UITextView typing changes to Bold/Unbold? So you can click it if there is no range and then start typing in bold...

Comment: Maybe by changing the `typingAttributes` when you don't have a `selectedRange`, and compare it with the attribute of the previous character.