# Change only fontsize of NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, font-size, nsattributedstring

I have a `NSAttributedString` that was loaded from a RTF file, so it already holds several font-attributes for different ranges. 
Now I want to adapt the font size to the screensize of the device, but when I add a whole new font attribute with a new size, the other fonts disappear.

Is there a way to change *only* the font size for the whole string?

Comment: Iterate the fonts attribute like (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021846/toggle-selectedrange-attributes-in-uitextview/56056187#56056187 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723345/nsattributedstring-change-the-font-overall-but-keep-all-other-attributes), when found, recreate the same font with different pointsize and apply it to the range.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only want to change the size of any given font found in the attributed string then you can do:

```
let newStr = someAttributedString.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
newStr.beginEditing()
newStr.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: newStr.string.utf16.count)) { (value, range, stop) in
    if let oldFont = value as? UIFont {
        let newFont = oldFont.withSize(20) // whatever size you need
        newStr.addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: range)
    }
}
newStr.endEditing()

print(newStr)
```

This will keep all other attributes in place.

If you want to replace all fonts in a given attributed string with a single font of a given size but keep all other attributes such as bold and italic, see:
[NSAttributedString, change the font overall BUT keep all other attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723345/nsattributedstring-change-the-font-overall-but-keep-all-other-attributes)

Comment: Quick question: is the `remoteAttribute` call really necessary? Always thought that `addAttribute` would be enough here.

Comment: @PauloMattos Good question. I suppose it isn't now that you point it out. Since the call to `addAttribute` is for the same attribute in the same range, the call to `removeAttribute` is unnecessary.

Comment: May I know why is it `newStr.string.utf16.count` instead of just `newStr.string.count`? And is it a good idea to always use the former when getting string count?