# How to change some text colors in multiple colored UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, textcolor

A UITextView has some text with black color and some with red color. I want to change only the black color to white color. I have no idea how to select only the black color and change it to white color.

Comment: NSAttributedString + enumerate the foreground attribute.

Comment: You can check how to enumerate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021846/toggle-selectedrange-attributes-in-uitextview/56056187#56056187 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102521/change-only-fontsize-of-nsattributedstring it's on the font attribute, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method [enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412461-enumerateattribute?language=objc)

Example Obj-C:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Test Attributed String"];
[string addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(3, string.length-3)];
[string enumerateAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    // value is color
}];
```